# Update state of a single element ( rest defaulting to constants )

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I am trying to make cards clickable and expandable, but when updating state, it occurs in all the cards . I just want to make the state change in only one card (the one on which the event occurred , in this case, a click event).
However, the state gets updated for every other cards. Currently this does work on one item but it needs to work on others too.

```
export default class TransactionCards extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        isHidden: true
    };
}

toggleHidden() {
    this.setState({
        isHidden: !this.state.isHidden
    });
}
renderCards() {
    return this.props.data.map((card, index) => (
        <View key={card.id}>
            <View style={styles.dateContainer}>
                <Text style={styles.dateText}>{card.time}</Text>
            </View>
            <Card>
                <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={this.toggleHidden.bind(this)}>
                    <View>
                        <View>
                            <View style={styles.transactionContainer}>
                                <Image
                                    style={styles.countryImage}
                                    source={require("../../assets/images/us-country-icon.png")}
                                />
                                <Text style={styles.transactionTitle}>{card.title}</Text>
                                <Text style={styles.transactionAmount}>{card.cost}</Text>

                                <Icon
                                    name={card.transactionType == "debit" ? "log-out" : "log-in"}
                                    type="feather"
                                    color={card.transactionType == "debit" ? "red" : "green"}
                                    size={18}
                                    iconStyle={styles.transactionIcon}
                                />
                            </View>
                            <View>
                                <Text style={styles.transactionBankDetails}>{card.bankDetails}</Text>
                            </View>
                        </View>
                        {/* Setting visiblity condition */}
                        {!this.state.isHidden && (
                            <View>
                                <Divider style={styles.CardItemDivider} />
                                <View display="flex" flexDirection="row" justifyContent="space-between">
                                    <View>
                                        <Text style={styles.transactionBankDetails}>
                                            {card.transactionCategory}
                                        </Text>
                                        <Text style={styles.transactionBankDetails}>{card.accountName}</Text>
                                    </View>
                                    <View>
                                        <Icon name="bell" type="feather" iconStyle={styles.transactionIcon} />
                                    </View>
                                </View>
                            </View>
                        )}
                    </View>
                </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
            </Card>
        </View>
    ));
}

render() {
    return <ScrollView showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>{this.renderCards()}</ScrollView>;
}
```

}

Comment: You could add a separate `isHidden` variable in state for each card.

Comment: can you show me how, there can be many cards  dynamiclly

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a new component for card and pass required params
2. Do the `toggleHidden` function inside the Card component

then inside the file it should look like

```
   <Card {SetYourPassedParams} />
   ......
```

Comment: you have multiple cards in single file. `<Card> .........</Card>`. You have to create a component for it and pass params

Answer (score 0):

You have two items connected to the same state value on the same state. If you want to separate the behaviours you have to separate the values too.

Comment: help by example

Comment: To do so in the best way, you should create the card class with it's own 'isHidden' property and toggleHidden function. Then insert in your application the cards you need and for each card pressed will be executed its toggleHidden which will affect only that one card in particular